# Xpath field contains case-insensitive string

Tags: sitecore-query

I've been searching here for a solution but at least when I've tried out the answers in the Xpath builder I always get errors.  I'm using Sitecore 8.2.  The current query is:

```
/sitecore/content/Documents//*[@@TemplateName='Document'and@Publication='1' and contains(@#Title#,'" + keyword + "')]
```

I just want to make the keyword insensitive to case.  I've tried forcing the title field item in the query to lowercase but I only get errors so apparently I'm not getting the syntax correct and can't seem to find a reference that gives syntax that doesn't produce an error...

When I try the following:

```
/sitecore/content/Documents//*[@@TemplateName='Document'and@Publication='1' and contains( translate(@Title,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'keyword')]
```

I get "String expression  expected in Contains().

I get the same when trying:

```
/sitecore/content/Documents//*[@@TemplateName='Document'and@Publication='1' and contains(lower-case(@Title), 'keyword')]
```

Comment: I would recommend using the Content Search API here instead of using XPath with a descendants tree walk. It will perform much better and your case insensitivity is simple to do.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to use the Search API and it's working as it should now.